# Stuck in Linkedin login via Webview

Tags: android, exception, linkedin-api

Actually my app is using linkedin login via linkedin app and webview. Login with linkedin is working fine but if in case linkedin app is not available i am using webview to process login. That was also working fine but today it suddenly stuck in some line of code exceptions. I am getting null access token in my Linkedin dialog class so i like to put try catch but after then it ll showing blank webview i don't know what to do know. here is my linkedin dialog code

```
public class LinkedinDialog extends Dialog
{
private ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;

public static LinkedInApiClientFactory factory;
public static LinkedInOAuthService oAuthService;
public static LinkedInRequestToken liToken;
private WebView mWebView;
private Context mContext;

public LinkedinDialog(Context context, ProgressDialog progressDialog) 
{
    super(context);
    mContext = context;
    this.progressDialog = progressDialog;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);// must call before super.
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ln_dialog);
    setWebView();
}

/**
 * set webview.
 */
private void setWebView()
{
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webkitWebView1);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    try {
        LinkedinDialog.oAuthService = LinkedInOAuthServiceFactory.getInstance().createLinkedInOAuthService(AppConstants.LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_KEY, AppConstants.LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_SECRET);
        LinkedinDialog.factory = LinkedInApiClientFactory.newInstance(AppConstants.LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_KEY, AppConstants.LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_SECRET);
        LinkedinDialog.liToken = LinkedinDialog.oAuthService.getOAuthRequestToken(AppConstants.OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL);

        mWebView.loadUrl(LinkedinDialog.liToken.getAuthorizationUrl());
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());

        mWebView.setPictureListener(new PictureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onNewPicture(WebView view, Picture picture) {
                if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }

            }
        });
    }catch (ExceptionInInitializerError e){
        AppLogs.printLogs("ExceptionInInitializerError :: " , " err ::");
        LinkedinDialog.this.dismiss();
        mWebView.goBack();
    }catch (NoClassDefFoundError ex){
        AppLogs.printLogs("NoClassDefFoundError :: " , " err ::");
        ex.printStackTrace();
        LinkedinDialog.this.dismiss();
        mWebView.goBack();
    }catch (Exception ee){
        LinkedinDialog.this.dismiss();
        mWebView.goBack();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        switch(keyCode)
        {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
                        mWebView.goBack();
                    } else {
                        cancel();
                    }

                return true;
        }

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient 
{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
    {
        if (url.contains(AppConstants.OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL))
        {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
            String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");

            cancel();

            for (OnVerifyListener d : listeners) 
            {
                // call listener method
                d.onVerify(verifier);
            }
        } 
        else if (url.contains("https://www.google.co.in/")) 
        {
            cancel();
        } 
        else 
        {
            Log.e("LinkedinSample", "url: " + url);
            view.loadUrl(url);
        }

        return true;
    }
}

/**
 * List of listener.
 */
private List<OnVerifyListener> listeners = new ArrayList<OnVerifyListener>();

/**
 * Register a callback to be invoked when authentication have finished.
 * 
 * @param data
 *            The callback that will run
 */
public void setVerifierListener(OnVerifyListener data)
{
    listeners.add(data);
}

/**
 * Listener for oauth_verifier.
 */
public interface OnVerifyListener 
{
    /**
     * invoked when authentication have finished.
     * 
     * @param verifier
     *            oauth_verifier code.
     */
    public void onVerify(String verifier);
}
}
```

this is function calls on login button

```
private void linkedInLogin()
{
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
    mProgressDialog.setMessage(AppConstants.sLoadingMsg);
    mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
    mProgressDialog.show();

    d = new LinkedinDialog(LoginActivity.this,mProgressDialog);
    d.show();

    d.setVerifierListener(new LinkedinDialog.OnVerifyListener() {

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onVerify(String verifier) {

            try {
                accessToken = LinkedinDialog.oAuthService.getOAuthAccessToken(LinkedinDialog.liToken, verifier);
                LinkedinDialog.factory.createLinkedInApiClient(accessToken);
                client = factory.createLinkedInApiClient(accessToken);

                AppLogs.printLogs("LinkedinSample", "ln_access_token: " + accessToken.getToken());
                mAccessTokenLogin = accessToken.getToken();

                com.google.code.linkedinapi.schema.Person p = null;

                p = client.getProfileForCurrentUser(EnumSet.of(
                        ProfileField.ID, ProfileField.FIRST_NAME,
                        ProfileField.LAST_NAME, ProfileField.HEADLINE,
                        ProfileField.SUMMARY, ProfileField.PUBLIC_PROFILE_URL,
                        ProfileField.INDUSTRY, ProfileField.PICTURE_URL,
                        ProfileField.LOCATION, ProfileField.LOCATION_NAME, ProfileField.EMAIL_ADDRESS));
                AppLogs.printLogs("linkedin id"," :: "+p.getId());
                UserLinkedInData userLinkedInData = UserLinkedInData.getInstance();
                try {
                    if (p.getEmailAddress() == null | p.getEmailAddress().isEmpty()) {
                        userLinkedInData.setmEmailAddress(AppConstants.sNotAvailable);

                    } else {
                        userLinkedInData.setmEmailAddress(p.getEmailAddress());
                    }
                }catch (Exception e){
                    userLinkedInData.setmEmailAddress(AppConstants.sNotAvailable);
                }

                try {
                    if (!p.getFirstName().isEmpty()) {
                        userLinkedInData.setmFirstName(p.getFirstName());
                    } else {
                        userLinkedInData.setmFirstName(AppConstants.sNotAvailable);
                    }
                }catch (Exception e){
                    userLinkedInData.setmFirstName(AppConstants.sNotAvailable);
                }

                }                         
        }
    });

    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

All jar dependencies :

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile project(':linkedin-sdk')
compile files('libs/linkedin-j-android.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.3.jar')
compile files('libs/signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar')
compile files('libs/signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.2.jar')
compile files('libs/signpost-jetty6-1.2.1.1.jar')
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
compile 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:7.0.4'
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0"
compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'}
```

Exception i am getting at first click :

```
W/System.err﹕ java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
W/System.err﹕ at com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInOAuthServiceImpl.getOAuthProvider(LinkedInOAuthServiceImpl.java:230)
W/System.err﹕ at com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInOAuthServiceImpl.getOAuthRequestToken(LinkedInOAuthServiceImpl.java:170)
W/System.err﹕ at com.app.util.LinkedinDialog.setWebView(LinkedinDialog.java:64)
W/System.err﹕ at com.app.util.LinkedinDialog.onCreate(LinkedinDialog.java:51)
W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:373)
W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:274)
W/System.err﹕ at com.app.circles.LoginActivity.linkedInLogin(LoginActivity.java:228)
W/System.err﹕ at com.app.circles.LoginActivity.access$100(LoginActivity.java:72)
W/System.err﹕ at com.app.circles.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:158)
```

and then i press back button to login again then getting new exception like this :

```
W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.constant.LinkedInApiUrls
```

Comment: Any chance you can post error log or stacktrace?

Comment: @jagmohan please check my updated question

Comment: I solved this issue by my self...i only clear build wrapper then i removed existing jar files of linkedin like linkedin-j , signpost-core, commons-codec and again import the same files then build project...now it is running well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by myself...i only clear build wrapper then i removed existing jar files for linkedin like linkedin-j , signpost-core, commons-codec and again import the same files then build project...now it is running well.

Comment: Happy to hear .Move ahead